# does big_writes option in mount command can cause file corruption?

Tags: ntfs

I've been transferring huge files about 5 gb from ext4 to ntfs and I have noticed the slow write speed about 1.5 to 2 MBps sometimes about 900 KBps. Now I've found out that adding "big_writes" option to the mount command would speed it up to about 25 MBps. Does this option can corrupt my files in my ntfs drive since because it is not used by default?